# Save Item Success Message using JS

Tags: javascript, custom-form

I would like a success message to show when updating (NOT CREATING) a list item in a custom sharepoint list. Is there a quick and dirty way of doing this using JS? I would like to avoid VS development if possible as this project is supposed to be a quick turnaround.

I already have a custom edit form in place.

An alternative would also be to send the user to a success page. I am really just looking for the simplest way possible at this point.

Comment: What do you mean confirmation message, "Are you sure you want to save your changes?" or something like this?

Comment: I guess you could call it more of a success message. "Your item has been saved"....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create custom edit form using SPD so that DataFormWebPart is generated:

[image]

Go to this form and edit it. Find the following code:

```
<SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton1"/>
```

Replace it with the following code:

```
<input type="button"
       value="Save"
       onclick="javascript: {ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent('__commit;__redirect={/Pages/MySuccessPage.aspx}')}" />
```

Do the same for

```
<SharePoint:SaveButton runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton2"/>
```

Save changes.

Now after editing user will be redirected to `/Pages/MySuccessPage.aspx`.

The approach is tested and based on my testing works fine both in SP2010 and SP2013.